# Different behaviour of case match pattern for strings

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I am trying to use strings in a case class like java switch-case statements  `switch(someString)`. But scala `match` statement always resolves to the first block.

```
whichTopic match {
  case accounts ⇒ {
    logger.info("!!!! ---- FOR ACCOUNTS --- !!! ")

  }
  case users ⇒ {
    logger.info("!!!! ---- FOR USERS --- !!! ")
    // TODO : Handle errors from the consumer
  }
}
```

Even when `whichTopic` value has `users`, it goes into the `accounts` block

Comment: `case x =>` will match all input because `x` is an unbound variable that can hold any value being matched against. `case accounts =>` is the same. You're creating a variable named `accounts` that can hold (and thus match) any value.

Comment: ahh...so i was never using the variable to identify which block it has to go to. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you didn't use it correctly - what you actually did is 2 cases of "alias" the `whichTopic` variable to `accounts` or `users` variables, but didn't specify what is "special" about them.

You should do something like:

```
whichTopic match {
  case accounts if accounts.startsWith("accounts") => logger.info("!!!! ---- FOR ACCOUNTS --- !!! ")
  case users if users.startsWith("users") => logger.info("!!!! ---- FOR USERS --- !!! ")
}
```

This is a case to check if is the strings start with `accounts` or `users`.

Of course, you can replace `startsWith` with any string method you want - like `contains` or something else which suits your case.

Answer (score 3):

> ahh...so i was never using the variable to identify which block it has to go to.

If you want to check equality to an existing variable, you can write

```
case x if x == accounts => ...
```

(as in Gal Naor's answer) or

```
case `accounts` => ...
```